# Build instructions Kodi on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, kodi

Are there any instructions for building Kodi on Raspbian?

I am looking for instructions for Kodi 17.0 (Krypton) on Raspbian 8.0 (Jessie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer at the [Kodi Forum](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=302929):

> They are compiled from [here](https://github.com/nsenica/xbmc/tree/krypton_rbp_backports), which is the upstream Kodi project, with popcornmix Raspberry Pi [patches](https://github.com/popcornmix/xbmc/tree/krypton_rbp_backports) plus some little changes that currently being proposed to be added upstream.

Instructions are at the bottom of these pages. However I have not tested them yet.